# Reformatting a String in Java

Tags: android, string, text, replace, split

For my app I have created a QR Code, then took that bitmap and added text to the bitmap, however I need the text not to extend longer then the bitmap is. So what I want to do is create an Array of the text by taking 25 characters then find the last index of (" ") in that 25 character section. at that space I want to be able to replace that space that was located with \n to start a new line.

So the plan is if I have a String that looks like "`Hello this is my name and I am longer than 25 charters and I have lots of spaces so that this example will work well.`"

I want it to out up this

```
Hello this is my name and
I am longer than 25 
charters and I have lots 
of spaces so that this 
example will work well.
```

To make this I counted 25 characters then went back to the most resent space, at that point I hit enter, I want my app to do this for me.

I am not very good at English so if something doesn't make sense tell me and I will try to explain it. Thanks

Comment: What should happen if there is a string of more than 25 characters without a space in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this but you can try it and tweak as necessary

```
String fullText = "your text here";
String withBreaks = "";
while( fullText.length() > 25 ){
    String line  = fullText.substring(0,24);
    int breakPoint = line.lastIndexOf( " ");
    withBreaks += fullText.substring(0,breakPoint ) + "\n";
    fullText = fullText.substring( breakPoint );
withBreaks += fullText;
```

Comment: So If I am not mistaken "withBreaks" us what I want to print out correct?

Comment: added a line at the end so as not to leave out the last few characters.

Answer (score 0):

char [] way (more C like):

```
 public static String reduceLength(String s, int len){
    char [] c = s.toCharArray();
    int i=len, j=0, k;
    while(true){
     for(k=j; k<=i; k++){
         if (k >= s.length()) return new String(c);
         if (c[k] == ' ') j=k;
     }
     c[j] = '\n';
     i= j+ len;
    }
}
```

This isn't safe, just something i threw together.